# Unable to install python 3.6.8 using pyenv -Build Failed OSX Error

Tags: python, homebrew, pyenv

I am trying to install an older python version 3.6.8 in my macbook using pyenv. 
Unfortunately, I came across this build OS X error which I am unable to resolve.
Appreciate if anyone knows how I do I resolve this, thanks.

```
(base) ➜  ~ pyenv install 3.6.8
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.6.8.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.8/Python-3.6.8.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.6.8...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.6 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/cn/d7tn5tls0jg6_dyn2853t6p40000gn/T/python-build.20200424220226.47493
Results logged to /var/folders/cn/d7tn5tls0jg6_dyn2853t6p40000gn/T/python-build.20200424220226.47493.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... darwin
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/cn/d7tn5tls0jg6_dyn2853t6p40000gn/T/python-build.20200424220226.47493/Python-3.6.8':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```